# Count data depends on sentence id and frequency of data

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have table :

```
=========================================================================
| id | stem_before | stem_after | stem_freq | sentence_id | document_id | 
=========================================================================
|  1 |     a       |     b      |    1      |   0         |       1     |    
|  2 |     c       |     d      |    1      |   0         |       1     |        
|  3 |     e       |     f      |    1      |   1         |       1     |
|  4 |     g       |     h      |    1      |   2         |       1     |
|  5 |     i       |     j      |    2      |   0         |       2     |
|  6 |     k       |     l      |    1      |   0         |       2     |
=========================================================================
```

I want to count in 2 steps :
step one is divide 1 with the sum the value of `stem_freq` in every `sentence_id` and `document_id`. step two is multiplication the result of the first step with the value of `stem_freq`

for example :

for data with `document_id` = 1 and `sentence_id` = 0, first step: `1/(1+1)` = 0.5, second step for `id` = 1 is `1*0.5` = 0.5. for `id` = 2 is `1*0.5` = 0.5.

for data with `document_id` = 2 and `sentence_id` = 0, first step: `1/(2+1)` = 0.3333, second step for `id` = 5 is `2*0.3333` = 0.6666, for `id` = 6 is `1*0.3333` = 0.3333.

here's my code :

```
$query = mysql_query ("SELECT sentence_id, document_id, stem_after, 
stem_freq,SUM(stem_freq) as freq 
FROM tb_stemming 
WHERE document_id ='$doc_id' 
GROUP BY(sentence_id)");

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
   $a    = $row['freq'];
   $freq = $row['stem_freq'];
   $tf   = $freq/$a;
}
```

but it only gives me result of the first data in every different sentence : can you help me. thank you :)

Comment: Just a quick comment; You should not be `SELECT`ing columns that are not in your `GROUP BY`. It is bad practice.

Comment: can you please explain this line : I want to `count tf` : `1/stem_freq` in every sentence and then multiply it with the `stem_after`. `stem_after` is a char in your table.Are you multiplying it? What is `tf`? What is the formula of counting `count`?

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob sorry if I can explain it in good way. `tf` and `count` is just a word to represent the calculations I need. Look at my example calculation above..

Comment: @igo in your first example , count=1/2 , from where this `2` is coming from? And tf=1*count , what's the source of the `1`

Comment: @MD.SahibBinMahboob 2 is coming from sum of `stem_freq` where the `sentence_id` is 0 and the `document_id` is 1. the source of `1` is data from `stem_freq`

Comment: @igo i guess you should add this to your question to let people dive in your question more easily rather then make them guessing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    a.*, 
    a.stem_freq * b.value
FROM
    tb_stemming as a
    JOIN 
    (
        SELECT
            document_id,
            sentence_id,
            1 / sum(stem_freq) 'value'
        FROM
            tb_stemming
        GROUP BY document_id, sentence_id
    ) as b
    ON a.document_id = b.document_id AND a.sentence_id = b.sentence_id
```